# Cannot open browser in perl program?

Tags: perl

I have a perl code which generates HTML report. After end of execution of program, I want to launch html file browser.

```
for (i<0; $i<$#files; $i++) {

   if (condition is met) {

       &sub_pass(prints to html file)

   }
   else {
       &sub_fail(prints to html file)
   }

 }

  my @url_report = "C://path/to/htmlfile/";
  system("explorer @url_report");
```

But this doesn't launch the html file, I want. When I call the System function before the for loop, it successfully opened the file. Any reason or solution and how can I make it work?

Comment: check the `File::Spec` perl module how to handle portable file-paths... :)

Comment: `explorer` is not a web browser. `iexplore` is (if you want to run Internet explorer only)

Comment: Please don't call subroutines using a `&`. That hasn't been required for a very long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`explorer` is a Windows program, and is not as forgiving as Perl about what path separator you use. That is, you need to use backslashes.

```
my $url_report = "C:\\path\\to\\htmlfile\\";
system("explorer $url_report");
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `url_report` here is an array, instead of a scalar:

```
my @url_report = "C://path/to/htmlfile/";
system("explorer @url_report");
```

You might try changing this from an array to a scalar, and you might also make use of the ability to retrieve an error message from `system()`:

```
my $url_report = "C://path/to/htmlfile/";
system("explorer $url_report") == 0 or die "could not open file: $url_report ($?)";
```

A more detailed error message will help you troubleshoot further.

Comment: Due to array interpolation rules, this should pass the exact same string to `system`. Granted, using scalars is better style, but this shouldn't be the source of the problem. Still, +1 for error handling

Answer (score 0):

```
"C://Users/path/output.html/"
```

should be

```
"C:\\Users\\path\\output.html"
```

Though it's possible `explorer` accepts the following (since the kernel does):

```
"C:/Users/path/output.html"
```

---

It would be even better if you used the browser of the user's choice:

```
my $url_report = "C:\\Users\\path\\output.html";
system(qq{start "" "$url_report"});
```

Comment: `start` is not a program but a `cmd`'s internal command, so `system` won't be able to run it. You should call cmd instead: `system(qq{cmd /c start "$url_report"});`

Comment: actually, `start` is a program and resides in `c:\windows\system32\start.exe\`...

Comment: @n0rd, that's wrong for three different reasons. 1) `start "$url_report"` will start a console titled `C:\path\to\htmlfile`, but won't actually run anything but `cmd` in that console. You shouldn't have removed the second argument. 2) When you pass a single argument to `system`, it is a shell command. `start "" "C:\path\to\htmlfile"` is a perfectly fine shell command. It doesn't matter that it invokes an internal command. 3) Even if I had used the multiple argument for of `system` which isn't suppose to execute stuff like internal commands like `dir` and `start`, it does anyway!

Comment: @Massa, hum? Not for me. It's an internal command in Win7. But as I pointed out in my previous comment, that's totally irrelevant.

Comment: That's weird. On one of my machines my version works and yours just does nothing, but on other your works and mine opens new cmd window.

Comment: @n0rd, Should work on all Windows machines. On Windows, `system($cmd)` is suppose to be the same as `system("cmd", "/x", "/c", $cmd)`. (Elsewhere, `system("sh", "-c", $cmd)`.) Maybe the `perl` on the machine where it doesn't work isn't actually running in Windows but in a unix emulation environment (cygwin)?

Comment: There's no way that works. `\t` will get replaced with a tab. You'll also get a number of warnings.

Comment: my $url_report = "C:\Users\path\output.html";
    system("explorer $url_report");

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!! You'll see you need to use  `my $url_report = "C:\\Users\\path\\output.html";` or `my $url_report = 'C:\Users\path\output.html';`

Comment: however, when I am trying call the perl script from a java program, it launches My Document folder instead of the html file. I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {perl, test.pl). Any reasons why this is behaving like this?

Comment: I don't follow. Ask this new question as a proper question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31962/discussion-between-chintan-pathak-and-ikegami)